# Can I use only JWT for authentication without widely used standards like OpenID/Oauth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid, stateless

I'm writing Rest Api and SPA. I want stateless authentication for users. That's why I would like to know is it still secure to use only JWTs without widely used standards like OpenID/Oauth2?

Answer (score 1):

JWT is a format of a token. OAuth2/OIDC is a protocol which tells you how you should obtain an access, refresh and ID token. There is no requirement that JWTs should be obtained only via OAuth or that OAuth flow should only use JWT. In fact, very often access and refresh tokens are opaque tokens, not JWTs. Also JWTs can be used for many other functions (e.g. Signed Request Objects).

This means that your system can issue JWTs, without using the protocol described in OAuth2/OIDC. That said, you must remember that standards are created so that we can we can achieve interoperability and protect from common security threats. Your system will be more secure if you implement OAuth2 or OIDC flow to obtain tokens, rather than figuring something out by yourself.